# Java EE servers are available like Weblogic,tomcat,Jboss,Websphere.....etc

Tags: tomcat, weblogic

We have so many Java EE servers are available like Weblogic,tomcat,Jboss,Websphere.....etc then how do we identify whether it is a application server  or Webserver(i need a proof) 
for example : Tomcat is Application server  and Weblogic is Webserver then my question is how do we know whether Tomcat is Application server  and Weblogic is Webserver(proof)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your question is wrong.

Tomcat is a web server and Weblogic is an application server.

**Webserver** : A server which provides the basic technology (support for Servlets, Jsp, http etc)stack to support a web application. Which means Java EE components like EJB, JMS, etc cannot be run or at least without third party support.

**Appserver** : A server which provides all the Java EE supported technology (Servlets, JSP, http, EJB, JMS etc. ) stack including the basics for a web server.  In-fact an appserver contains an inbuilt webserver to support web applications and has several other functionalities.

And about having so-many webservers and appservers, it is similar to having different brands of commodities (mainly prevents monopoly in my view). Hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

A webserver is usually the placed in front of an application server in production. Just like a load balancer is usually placed in front of a web server, and a firewall in front of a load balancer.

Their purpose is usually to filter and serve traffic to Java EE containers and to serve static pages. Web Servers do not usually compile Java EE code (Apache, Iplanet, IBM HTTP Server etc), that is usually done on the Application servers.

However web servers can run regular expressions, cgi scripts, perl, and some can run code like ASP for example on the IIS web server. But when it comes to Java EE only Application servers run this code, like Websphere, Tomcat, Weblogic, JBoss, etc.